# How can I get data from promise in typescript class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http

So I'm making an app for searching movies using Movie API. I refer to other person's code, and they have a separate class with all api methods, I use one method for now and the class looks like this:

```
  export default class TMDb {
  private readonly API_BASE = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
  private readonly TMDB_API_KEY = '{api_key}';
  private readonly API_LANGUAGE = 'en-US';
  public readonly API_IMAGE_PATH = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/';


  private fetchJSON = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data;
  };

  public getPopularMovies = async (page = 1): Promise<ISearch<IMovie>> => {
    return this.fetchJSON(
      `${this.API_BASE}movie/popular?api_key=${this.TMDB_API_KEY}&language=${this.API_LANGUAGE}&page=${page}`
    );
  };
}
```

And I'm trying to get the data in an App component like this:

```
const API = new TMDb();

  useEffect(() =>{
      const movies = API.getPopularMovies();
      console.log(movies);
  }, [])
```

But in the console I see only a promise. So my question is, how could I get the data from the promise in the useEffect hook? So I could use this data further

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```
const API = new TMDb();

useEffect(() => {
   const fetchPopularMovies = async () => { 
      const data = await API.getPopularMovies();
      // your state
      setPopularMovies(data)
   }
   fetchPopularMovies().catch(e => {})
}, [])
```

But you do not need to use a class for TMDb and just put your functions inside a file and then export them. It means maybe you do not need to use OOP paradigm.